# Angular 8 add class after page load Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular8

As the title suggests, I am trying to add a class to a `div` element after the page is load! I have a condition `isTrue`, and the angular function `ngAfterViewInit()` that executes after the page is loaded making `isTrue` value to be `true`, then adding the class `hideOnLoad`. Of course I could use standard `javascript` or `jquery`, but I must do it the angular way. Essentially the end result should be that, the `div.index-logo-wrapper` fades out slowly after the page is laod. My idea was to add a class once its loaded that gradually decreases the `opacity` You input is much appreciated.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-index-section',
  templateUrl: './index-section.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./index-section.component.scss']
})
export class IndexSectionComponent implements OnInit {
  isTrue: boolean = false;
  public innerWidth: any;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.innerWidth = window.innerWidth;
    if (this.innerWidth < 1000) {
      this.isTrue = true;
      alert(this.isTrue);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="index-section">
  <div class="index-logo-wrapper" [class.hideOnLoad]="isTrue">
    <figure>
      <img src="assets/icons/logo_mobile.svg" alt=" logo">
    </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="index-media-wrapper">
    <div class="media-container">
      <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/128014070?autoplay=1&color=ffffff&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Itaque contra est, ac dicitis; Duo Reges: constructio interrete. Videsne quam sit magna dissensio?
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

This is the error in my console:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not change things related to bindings inside Angular hooks because that's messing with change detection process. Consider change detection as if it was a meat grinder. You should only try to change the meat before it goes in or after it went out — you cannot alter it in the middle of the process.

What you can do is turn it into an RxJs Stream and use it with `async` pipe in the template. This way Angular would know that something has changed during change detection and will retrigger it again once it's done.

Or you can inject `ChangeDetectorRef` and do `this.changeDetectorRef.markForCheck()` in places where you changed something related to bindings within lifecycle hooks. It is effectively the same as `async` pipe for your case.

That is more general suggestion, here's the solution to your particular case that also works with Angular Universal (server side rendering):

```js
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-index-section',
  templateUrl: './index-section.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./index-section.component.scss']
})
export class IndexSectionComponent {
  readonly isTrue: boolean;

  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) {defaultView}: Document) {
    this.isTrue = !defaultView || defaultView.innerWidth < 1000;
  }
}
```

Of course there will be no window size on the server, but accessing properties on `window` can cause errors in that environment and it is preferable not to use DOM API in your Angular app directly and use abstractions through tokens anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your input! Conceptionally it makes sense, the meat grinder is a good example! Now I just have to figure out how that can be implemented in my case...

Comment: Does my approach to what I want to do make sense tho?

Comment: In your case what I would do is I would create a readonly propery and assign it in constructor. That is, if you only want to set it once.

Comment: Updated my answer. If you want this dynamic, you can create an observable from resize events on window and use it with `async` pipe. This way you can also add throttling to not hurt performance on rapid resize events.

Answer (score 0):

You can add class dynamically using ternary operator `?`. If `isTrue` then add `hideOnLoad`, otherwise class is empty:

```
<div class="index-logo-wrapper" [ngClass]="isTrue ? 'hideOnLoad' : ''">
```

Answer (score 0):

You dynamically add class by either

```html
<div class="index-logo-wrapper" [ngClass]="{'hideOnLoad':isTrue}">
```

or

```html
<div class="index-logo-wrapper  {{isTrue ? 'hideOnLoad' : ''}}">
```

Comment: The 2nd one isn't valid.

Comment: Both works for me. don't know what went wrong for you @AntoineB

Answer (score 0):

As the other said, you can use the following solution:

```
<div class="index-logo-wrapper" [ngClass]="isTrue ? 'hideOnLoad' : ''">
```

But I like this other syntax better when it's for a single class:

```
<div class="index-logo-wrapper" [class.hideOnLoad]="isTrue">
```

It is easier to read and cleaner.

Comment: Yes I prefer using the second syntax (as is used), the issue is that it won't work! My code is the same as your, question is what am I doing wrong?